# Nginx - Why does nginx use so much cpu and memory? How to fix?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, centos8

I am having problem with nginx consuming a lot of ram and cpu space.
Even though I used the command

> sudo kill -9 1254214

to kill it, but it turned back on automatically after a while.

[image]

If anybody face the problem and know how to fix it.Hope you'll help me to solve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: It depends on a large number of variables, including the system specs, what Nginx is hosting, etc.

Comment: @WillWalsh Do you have a solution?

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `log_format` in `/etc/nginx.conf` to

```
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr $http_x_forwarded_for [$time_iso8601] '
                      '$status $request_length $body_bytes_sent $request_time $upstream_response_time '
                      '"$request" "$http_referer" $ssl_protocol/$ssl_cipher $ssl_ciphers';
```

and enable it in `access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;`

Then you can see how much time it takes to serve each individual request and whether it uses CPU-intensive SSL cipher. Once you know the most heavy-load URLs - you should have a better idea why they are slow.